# Unable to run icacls on multiple directories at one time in a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, batch

I'm able to run pretty much any command multiple times in one batch file.
Example:

```
MD \\directory\local\Local\New1
MD \\directory\local\Local\New2
MD \\directory\local\Local\New3
MD \\directory\local\Local\New4
MD \\directory\local\Local\New5
```

This will create me five new directories in one .bat file.

BUT IF I do this:

```
icacls \\directory\local\Local\New1 /grant domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
icacls \\directory\local\Local\New2 /grant domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
icacls \\directory\local\Local\New3 /grant domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
icacls \\directory\local\Local\New4 /grant domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
icacls \\directory\local\Local\New5 /grant domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

Nothing happens.  I have tried using & and && at the end also.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

For whatever reason, if I use cmd /k at the begining of each command it will complete the first line only. What the heck?  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The `\\directory` syntax is strange - do you mean a network share?

Comment: may try `"...(x)(y)(z)"` or `...(x^)(yˆ)(zˆ)` in: `"domain\domain_group:(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)"` or  `domain\domain_group:(OIˆ)(CIˆ)(IOˆ)(Mˆ)`